# preg match remove captured in previous group

Tags: php, preg-match

I need to split strings into parts. Matched patterns must not be present in other matched groups. Example strings:

```
baranything
baranythingbaz
```

Expected output:

```
array(
    0 => baranything
    1 => bar
    2 => anything
    3 =>
)
array(
    0 => baranything
    1 => bar
    2 => anything
    3 => baz
)
```

The simplest solution could be like `(bar)(.*)(baz|)` but it puts all remaining string into the [2] element and the "baz" is not captured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(bar)(.*?)(baz|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BIkNSU/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(bar)(.*%3F)(baz%7C%24)):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string

  - `(bar)` - Group 1: `bar`
  - `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
  - `(baz|$)` - either `baz` or end of string.